# error trying to delete a table row: UITableView internal bug

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using the method that the User has the option to delete the object besides others. When I click to 'Remover' I get the following error:

reason: 'UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'

this is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let position = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Posição", handler: { (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in
            tableView.editing = false
        })

        let remove = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Destructive, title: "Remover", handler: { (action: UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in
            self.tableData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        })

        return [remove, position]
    }
```

I really need to use the method editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: you need to delete the object from datasource as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the object from the table data source first.

Try this

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: How many rows do you have when you try to delete? Just one or more?

Comment: I have two rows and I receive this error when I delete one